# Apply patch for boost installation

Tags: boost, build, debian, patch

I have installed Boost lib [ver 1.72](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_72_0.html) successfully (on Debian 10), but now realized there is a known issue (that i have already faced) and there is a [patch](https://www.boost.org/patches/1_72_0/0001-revert-cease-dependence-on-range.patch).

Searched a lot but didn't find a guide on how to apply/install/build this patch. Do I have to rebuild the whole lib? How to apply the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the patch, you can see the path it applies to:
boost/coroutine/asymmetric_coroutine.hpp

From the directory containing the boost directory (where the path starts) you want to run:

```
patch -p1 < /path/to/file.patch
```

and then rebuild the library.

Comment: I use the command, but got `can't find file to patch at input line 17. Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?` I know exactly what file must be patched but for sure what to do about this error?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I think you need to do -p1 to strip off the a/ part of the path from the diff. This is from the temporary paths used by git to have 2 copies of the file to diff as far as I know.